# hide div class using @media in css

Tags: css, media

I am trying to hide an email div class when the screen size is made smaller.

I have done this for a div class which includes a set of columns but can't hide a div class containing the logged in user's email address.

```
<div class="cert">
    <h1 class="certname">
        <?php
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        echo 'Hi, <a href="https://vle.uxbridge.ac.uk/intranet/members/' . $current_user->user_login . '/profile/change-avatar/">' . $current_user->display_name . '</a>' . "\n";

        ?></h1>
    <h2 class="certemail">
        <?php
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        echo '<a href="https://outlook.office.com/owa/" target="_blank">' . $current_user->user_email . '</a>' . "\n";

        ?>
    </h2>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
.cert { display:none !important; }
}
```

Comment: once check the screen width with 300 or less and check with chrome's responsive tool. it should work.

Comment: Once check if the style is getting applied to the element when your screen size is <= 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media query should work, note however that 300px is a very small size, it's smaller than most mobile devices (320px is the iPhone 4 screen resolution).

Your media query will set the `.cert` div to `display: none !important` when the screen size is less than or equal to 300px - is this the behaviour you want?

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide only email or total div ?
If you want to hide only email, then the css should be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
.cert .certemail{ display:none !important; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
.cert{ display:none; }
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cert">
    <h1 class="certname">
        <?php
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        echo 'Hi, <a href="https://vle.uxbridge.ac.uk/intranet/members/' . $current_user->user_login . '/profile/change-avatar/">' . $current_user->display_name . '</a>' . "\n";

        ?></h1>
    <h2 class="certemail">
        <?php
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        echo '<a href="https://outlook.office.com/owa/" target="_blank">' . $current_user->user_email . '</a>' . "\n";

        ?>
    </h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```